# Github Actions | google cloud authentication

Tags: google-cloud-platform, github-actions

I am building a github actions workflow and I am failing to authenticate into google cloud.

I get the following error : google-github-actions/auth failed with: failed to parse service account key JSON credentials: unexpected token '', "#�H@�" is not valid JSON

My credentials key is stores as a secret in github

Here is my yaml

```
steps:
      - name: Checkout code into workspace directory
        uses: actions/checkout@v4
 
      - name : Authenticate Google Cloud
        env: 
          GCP_SECRET: ${{ secrets.GCP_CREDENTIALS }}
        uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
        with:
          credentials_json: $GCP_SECRET
```

Comment: Changed the approach and used the Workload Identity Federation through a Service Account method  to authenticate, there is a guide on how to set it up in GCP and in the YAML file it is passed as follows :
`- name: Authenticate Google Cloud
            uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2
            with:
              service_account: 'your-service account'
              workload_identity_provider: 'your-workload-identity-provider'`

Comment: Thanks for your response. Since the above comment mentioned by you has helped  in overcoming the issue, let me know to convert the comment as a response to have greater visibility to community members or else can you provide the same as answer and accept it.

Comment: Yes you can convert it, the guide is here : https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setup

Comment: Thank you I have edited the answer and  accept the answer for the greater visibility of the community.

Answer (score 1):

As per the error seems to be you have given invalid json file of service account which is not parsed by the Git actions workflow.  As per this [official github](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#sake) :

1. (Optional) Create a Google Cloud Service Account. If you already have a Service Account, take note of the email address and skip this step :

> ```
>     # TODO: replace ${PROJECT_ID} with your value below.             
>     gcloud iam service-accounts create "my-service-account" \
>       --project "${PROJECT_ID}"
> ```

2. Create a Service Account Key JSON for the Service Account.

> ```
> # TODO: replace ${PROJECT_ID} with your value below.
> gcloud iam service-accounts keys create "key.json" \
>   --iam-account "my-service-account@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
> ```

3. Upload the contents of this file as a [GitHub Actions Secret](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/security-guides/using-secrets-in-github-actions).  Use the name of the GitHub Actios secret as the credentials_json value in the GitHub Actions YAML:

> ```
>  uses: 'google-github-actions/auth@v2'
>   with:
>       credentials_json: '${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CREDENTIALS }}' # Replace with the name of your GitHub Actions secret
> ```

Can you validate the above steps as per your yaml seems to be you need to give correct service account JSON file and also credentials json format need to be taken care.

---------- or else you can also achieve by using Workload Identity Federation through a Service Account by following this [official github](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth?tab=readme-ov-file#sake)

**Edit :** Sinethemba Nontshintshi, achieved this by Changing the approach and used the Workload Identity Federation through a Service Account method to authenticate, by using this [guide](https://github.com/google-github-actions/auth#setup) on how to set it up in GCP and in the YAML file it is passed as follows :

```
 - name: Authenticate Google Cloud             
   uses: google-github-actions/auth@v2             
   with: 
     service_account: 'your-service account'              
     workload_identity_provider: 'your-workload-identity-provider'
```

Comment: So I ended up changing the authentication to use the Workload Identity Federation through a Service Account method  and now this is not a problem, I had passed the correct json file though and I even followed the instructions to minify it and save it into github secrets as a one line.